# Why is GAE dev_appserver only setting ETag, but not Expires HTTP header?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml, dev-appserver, dev-appserver-2

## File & Folder Structure

I have the following directory structure.

```
[app_root]
|
|---[static]
    |
    |--- [css]
    |--- [img]
    |--- [js]
         |--- [app]
         |--- [libs]
         |--- main.js
         |--- require.js
```

## App.yaml

The `app.yaml` config for `static_dir` handlers are set to different expiration time.

```yaml
application: my-app-name
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

default_expiration: "10d"

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon\.ico
  expiration: "364d"

- url: /static/img
  static_dir: static/img
  expiration: "364d"
  http_headers:
    X-Static-Img: Moo1

- url: /static/css
  static_dir: static/css
  expiration: "15m"
  http_headers:
    X-Static-Css: Moo2

- url: /static/js/app
  static_dir: static/js/app
  expiration: "15m"
  http_headers:
    X-Static-Js-App: Moo4

- url: /static/js/libs
  static_dir: static/js/libs
  expiration: "7d"
  http_headers:
    X-Static-Js-Libs: Moo5

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: static/js
  expiration: "15m"
  http_headers:
    X-Static-Js-Root: Moo3

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 12d
  http_headers:
    X-Static-ROOT: MOOOOOOOOOOO COW
```

## HTTP Headers

### /static/css - first time

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

======================
   Request Headers
======================
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:dev_appserver_login="test@admin.com:True:113617613220115205203"
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31

======================
   Response Headers
======================
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-length:103314
Content-type:text/css
Date:Mon, 06 May 2013 17:46:22 GMT
ETag:"MTgwMTU4MDk3NA=="
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Server:Development/2.0
X-Static-Css:Moo2
```

### /static/css - subsequent requests

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

======================
   Request Headers
======================
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:dev_appserver_login="test@admin.com:True:113617613220115205203"
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
If-None-Match:"MTgwMTU4MDk3NA=="
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31

======================
   Response Headers
======================
Date:Mon, 06 May 2013 17:53:20 GMT
ETag:"MTgwMTU4MDk3NA=="
Server:Development/2.0
```

## Problem

On initial request, `Expires` header is set to `Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT` in the past.
I assume it should be set to `"15m"` into the future at least based on the `app.yaml`.

But all subsequent requests only use the `ETag` to get the `HTTP 304 Not Modified`.
The `Expires` header is completely missing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Soe

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with dev_appserver2.  I see the same thing as you.

When I'm using the old dev_appserver, mine is working with a proper expires header on the first request, but I'm not setting any extra headers.

I don't see expire heaers on the 304 reply either though, but that seems fine.

The old dev_appserver is closer to the production behavior, but there's still some slight differences in the headers generated.